# Watch element position and react to changes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with a fairly complex view in AngularJS, but only a small number of elements are scrolled into view on the page at any one time.  So ideally I want to be able to pause watchers on the children of elements that are scrolled off screen, for performance purposes.

The scrollbar I'm using seems to "virtually" scroll by adjusting its "top" property.  So my markup looks like this when it's partially scrolled down:

```
<div id="mCSB_3_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_x_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_x" style="position: relative; top: -123px; left: 0px; width: 100%;" dir="ltr">
    <div id="table-1" pause-watchers></div>
    <div id="table-2" pause-watchers></div>
    <div id="table-3" pause-watchers></div>
</div>
```

So in my "pauseWatchers" directive I'm trying to watch the table elements' offset positions and do further processing if they're beyond the boundaries of the screen.  This is what I have so far:

```
app.directive('pauseWatchers', function(){
return {
    link: function (scope, element) {

        scope.$watch(function () {
                        return element.offset().top; 
                    },
                    function (newValue, oldValue) {
                        console.log(newValue + ' : ' + oldValue);
                        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                          //further processing goes here
                        }
                    }
        );
    }
}
});
```

The watcher isn't working how I need it to.  Basically the only time it picks up the offset value is on page load and if I click the element.

How do I make it watch for changes to the offset value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the watchExpression doesn't get called because scrolling through **#mCSB_3_container** (and in any other containers for that matter) doesn't trigger a [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle.

This means that you should add a callback for the on scroll event on **#mCSB_3_container** which triggers a digest cycle.

Something like this (it could be refactored into a directive):

```
// ... code ...
angular
    .element($document[0].querySelector('#mCSB_3_container'))
    .on('scroll', function () {
      $rootScope.$evalAsync();
    });
// ... code ...
```

For this I would highly recommend using a [**debounced function**](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) in order to increase performance.

**TL;TR:** I found [this library](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-scroll-watch) which should help you as it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, both of those suggestions looked really promising but unfortunately don't seem to work.  I think it's because of the way the scrollbar is working; it just seems to shift its "top" property without actually firing a scroll event.  I tested this by setting up an event-listener breakpoint on "scroll" and it doesn't get hit when I'm scrolling.  Is there any way to $watch changes to the position of an element without relying on a scroll event?

Comment: I'm guessing the scrollbar listens to the scroll event and stops it propagation. A *dumb and fast* solution would be to set an interval function and constantly trigger digest cycles.

Comment: I just saw that you're using [malihu scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/). A good fix would be to register a callback on **[whileScrolling](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#plugin-data-callbacks-whileScrolling)** which simply triggers a digest cycle. Don't forget to use a **debounced function**.

Comment: Perfect, thank you - this was the missing link in the chain!